# Adding Android Library: Only a type can be imported. com.project.test.networktasklibrary resolves to a package

Tags: java, android, import, shared-libraries

I'm attempting to implement part of my source code as a library and I've added the library to the project under properties > android > Reference however when I attempt to use the library by calling:

```
import. com.project.test.networktasklibrary;
```

I'm getting an error stating:

```
 Only a type can be imported. com.project.test.networktasklibrary resolves to a package
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
import com.project.test.networktasklibrary.*;
```

Instead

Or:

```
import com.project.test.networktasklibrary.ExactClassName;
```

Comment: I tried adding the asterisk - eclipse states it needs to be removed - I also tried adding the specific class name - and eclipse states: 
The type com.project.test.networktasklibrary.NetworkTask is not visible

Comment: One more question... when I attempt to implement the library by calling:

 NetworkTask();

I'm getting an error stating -The method NetworkTask() is undefined for the type ConfigFinalActivity - any suggestions?